# Is the iMac 27 5K good for rendering?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Is the iMac 27 running at 5K resolution good for rendering with blender?

**GPU:** AMD Radeon R9 M295X with 4GB GDDR5

**CPU:** Intel i7 4.0ghz (Turbo 4.4ghz)

Comment: Imacs and Mac "Pro" with AMD processors are not great for rendering in cycles using GPU.

Answer (score 2):

Your "best" is hard to answer. Blender can use CPU and GPU for rendering. Here's an overview of a hundred or so CPU and GPU test renders:
http://blenchmark.com/benchmarks-overview

Here's a sample of the data, where shorter lines mean faster renders:
[image]

In Cycles rendering, when you select GPU rendering, several of the initial file preparation steps are completed on CPU, then image rendering begins on your GPU. So a fast GPU is great, but a fast CPU still helps.

So "best" is pretty much always the most CPU, RAM, GPU and VRAM you can afford... but the benchmarks will help you see where economies exist.